When is a vector bundle on a Shimura variety an automorphic vector bundle?
Let $(G, X)$ be a Shimura datum, let $K \subset G(\mathbb{A}_f)$ be an open compact subgroup, and denote by $\text{Sh}_K(G,X)$ the Shimura variety whose complex points are given by $G(\mathbb{Q})\backslash X \times G(\mathbb{A}_f)/K$.
Let $\hat{X}$ denote the compact dual of $X$, and $\beta : X \to \hat{X}$ the Borel embedding. Let $\mathcal{J} \to \hat{X}$ be a $G_\mathbb{C}$-equivariant vector bundle. By an automorphic vector bundle on $\text{Sh}_K(G,X)$, I mean a vector bundle of the form
$$\mathcal{V}_K(\mathcal{J}) := G(\mathbb{Q}) \backslash \beta^*(\mathcal{J}) \times G(\mathbb{A}_f)/K$$
Let's say I have an arbitrary vector bundle $\mathcal{W}$ on $\text{Sh}_K(G,X)$. Are there known conditions on $\mathcal{W}$ which allow one to conclude that $\mathcal{W} = \mathcal{V}_K(\mathcal{J})$ for some $\mathcal{J}$?
The context of my question is the following: if I have an automorphic vector bundle $\mathcal{V}^0_K(\mathcal{J})$ on a connected component $\text{Sh}_K(G,X)^+$, and I am able to lift $\mathcal{V}^0_K(\mathcal{J})$ to a vector bundle on $\text{Sh}_K(G,X)$, under what conditions will the resulting vector bundle be automorphic?
